# Prove that any polynomial in $F[x]$ can be written in a unique manner as a product of irreducible polynomials in F[x].

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Prove that any polynomial in $F[x]$ can be written in a unique manner as a product of irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$.

$F$ is a field of fractions of a UFD.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem. It is one of my lecture note result, but my lecturer did not provide a proof.

Comment: $F[x]$ is not a field, and in particular not a field of fractions. It __is__ a UFD, but that is what your question seems to be asking. By the way, fields do not contain any irreducible elements.

Comment: see  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218325/why-is-fx-a-ufd/1218346#1218346)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the letter $F$ was chosen to indicate a field, although the question does not say so.

This is just an instance of the [general fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Properties) that Euclidean domains (or more generally principal ideal domains) are unique factorisation domains. The usual proof passes by establishing [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) for irreducible elements, which serves to show that given two factorisations, any irreducible factor in the factorisation on the left can also be found (up to an invertible factor) in the factorisation on the right. The proof really matches that for the integers in all respects.

Comment: Is it true that if a polynomial is irreducible in r[x], then it is irreducible in F[x] and vice versa? Is it true tat if R[x] is a UFD, then F[x] is a UFD? I am very confused why F[x] is a UFD, when I only know that R[x] is a UFD.

Comment: @user136266: Your comment fails to explain what $R$ is (the question does not say what $F$ is either, but my answer assumed it was a field). It is a fact that $F[X]$ is a UFD for _any_ field $F$. It applies in particular if (as maybe you meant) $F$ is the field of fractions of an integral domain $R$. But this is independent of whether $R[X]$ is an UFD or not (it might well not be).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Can I know how to prove that F[x] is a UFD for any field F?

Comment: @user2675516: That is exactly what my answer explains. It is basically because $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain (since one has Euclidean division in $F[x]$).